# Unable to run Django server after executing custom python code

Tags: django, python-3.x

I reconstructed a Django boilerplate (Django 3.0.2, Python 3.7.5) where I divided the settings as different files for production and development separately inside **production.py** and **development.py** respectively. Here, **src** was renamed from **main**. They both import everything from **base.py**. The folder structure of my project looks like this:

```
-Django_boilerplate
    -src
        -core
            -migrations
            -management
                -commands
                    -rename.py  
        -main
            -settings
                -base.py
                -development.py
                -production.py
        -templates
        -db.sqlite3
        -manage.py
```

I wrote the **rename.py** so that whenever I work on a new project, I can just start the project by running this file to rename the project accordingly. My **rename.py** file looks like this:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import os

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Renames a Django project'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('new', type=str, help='The new Django project name')

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_project_name = kwargs['new'][0]

        files_to_rename = ['main/settings/base.py', 
            'main/asgi.py', 
            'main/wsgi.py', 'manage.py']
        folder_to_rename = 'main'

        for f in files_to_rename:
            with open(f, 'r') as file:
                filedata = file.read()

            filedata = filedata.replace(folder_to_rename, new_project_name)

            with open(f, 'w') as file:
                file.write(filedata)

        os.rename(folder_to_rename, new_project_name)
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(f'Project has been renamed to {new_project_name}'))
```

Then I executed the rename.py file by running

```
python manage.py rename ecommerce
```

The first time, it executed and changed the settings as

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ecommerce.settings.development')
```

in **manage.py** and

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ecommerce.settings')
```

in the **asgi.py** & **wsgi.py** files but not in the **base.py** where the values of ROOT_URLCONF and WSGI_APPLICATION didn't change.

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'main.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'main.wsgi.application'
```

After this, I am unable to run the server as well as rename the project anymore. Whenever I run the server or the **rename.py** file, no error message is displayed on the command prompt. I referenced this from a GitHub repo https://github.com/justdjango/django_project_boilerplate

I could have just cloned or copied the codes but wanted to know what can be done. What seems to be my mistake?
EDIT1: Added Django and Python version details
EDIT2: I also manually changed all the names that got changed in these files from **ecommerce** to **main** back again to try to see if that worked but it didn't.

Comment: You shouldn't be executing Django management scripts directly (`python rename.py ecommerce`) they should usually be run via `manage.py` (`python manage.py rename ecommerce`)

Comment: I am so sorry I meant to type that instead. I kind of noticed it now after your comment. My problem still exists after this though. Thanks for spotting. Will edit question.